# QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission problem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-permissions, google-play-console

I have created a social media app in Flutter and I am getting images from user with Camera or Gallery. That's why I'm using the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission. The problem is that Google Play rejected my app every time because I was using the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission. But i should use that permission because when I delete this permission from my AndroidManifest, I am not getting images from the user. How can I get this permission approved by Google Play without deleting it from my AndroidManifest? Or is there another method that will delete this permission and continue to get photos from the user?

Comment: what you mean by "to get photos from the user"? what code are you using?

Comment: Im using ImagePicker();

Comment: so what do you need `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` for? why do you need to query all installed packages?

Comment: I dont know but when im deleting QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES Permission i am not getting image from Camera, probably i should use another permission for Camera

Comment: I don't know exactly what QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES do

Answer (score 0):

Instead of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES, you can list [intent filter signatures](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#intent-filter-signature) in your  element. Your app can then discover apps that have matching  elements.

```
<queries>
       
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```